# SQL Union All in Django Orm

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django-models, django-orm

I am currently working on a project in which I have below-described tables, using below table I want to make a query which will show remaining stock position so I want to make using `Union All` in Django ORM, by using `union all` in query I will manage my stock position, I have run the `SQL` query which I also described below, produce expected result.

```py
class PurchaseHeader(models.Model):
    purchase_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    footer_description = models.TextField()
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cartage_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    additional_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    withholding_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    account_id = models.ForeignKey(ChartOfAccount, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)


class PurchaseDetail(models.Model):
    item_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_description = models.TextField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    cost_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sales_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    purchase_id = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseHeader, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class PurchaseReturnHeader(models.Model):
    purchase_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    footer_description = models.TextField()
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cartage_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    additional_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    withholding_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    account_id = models.ForeignKey(ChartOfAccount, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

class PurchaseReturnDetail(models.Model):
    item_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_description = models.TextField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    cost_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sales_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    purchase_return_id = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseReturnHeader, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class SaleHeader(models.Model):
    sale_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    footer_description = models.TextField()
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cartage_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    additional_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    withholding_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    account_id = models.ForeignKey(ChartOfAccount, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)


class SaleDetail(models.Model):
    item_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_description = models.TextField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    cost_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sales_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sale_id = models.ForeignKey(SaleHeader, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class SaleReturnHeader(models.Model):
    sale_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    footer_description = models.TextField()
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cartage_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    additional_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    withholding_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    account_id = models.ForeignKey(ChartOfAccount, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,)


class SaleRetutnDetail(models.Model):
    item_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_description = models.TextField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    cost_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sales_tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    sale_return_id = models.ForeignKey(SaleReturnHeader, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And I want to make a query like this

```
SELECT item_code, SUM(quantity) AS qty FROM (
    SELECT 'Purchase' AS TranType,Item_Code,Quantity FROM transaction_purchasedetail
    UNION All
    SELECT 'Purchase Return' AS TranType,Item_Code,Quantity * -1 FROM transaction_purchasereturndetail
    UNION All
    SELECT 'Sale' AS TranType,Item_Code,Quantity * -1 FROM transaction_saledetail
    UNION All
    SELECT 'Sale Return' AS TranType,Item_Code,Quantity  FROM transaction_saleretutndetail
) AS tblTemp GROUP BY Item_Code
```

I have run the above SQL query in DB Browser SQLite and I got expected result
How can I do this in Django ORM.

Comment: You can execute raw SQL in Django. Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/) link.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#union

`union` has an `all` kwargs:

```
qs.union(another_qs, all=True)
```